# Amazon EC2 Cloud Infrastructure

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-computing

What type of hardware and virtualization solution does Amazon EC2 utilize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer for certain but googling for [amazon ec2 hypervisor] indicates that people think that they use Xen ([article here](http://www.techworld.com.au/article/343852/linux_kvm_virtualization_gains_steam_cloud_computing_market/?fp=39&fpid=29527&rid=1#)) on various Intel chips ([blog here](http://huanliu.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/amazons-physical-hardware-and-ec2-compute-unit/)).

Answer (score 1):

George, this should help answer the question http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/